# self is not defined in angular server side rendering

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am following [angular ssr](https://angular.io/guide/universal) this tutorial everything setup is successfully done and also these command run successfully `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr` then they Exit status 1 I got the **error** **ERROR ReferenceError: self is not defined**

[console error in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W85NL.png)

[installed angular version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJKVV.png)

Comment: Can we see the relevant code where you have defined `if ("document" in self)`? Is that your code? Possibly [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898143/self-is-not-defined-in-ionic-angular-server-side-rendering) has an answer?

Comment: if its your code try replacing self with globalThis https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Comment: No its angular generated file main.ts have this code. @daddygames I followed this article its not solved the problem. I also use domino and set globally self but still have an error

Comment: Open up your main.js file at the specified position and try to see if yu can figure out which module is causing this error